# UK Standard Visitor visa refusal. Should I reapply?

Tags: visa-refusals, vietnamese-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK Standard Visitor visa early for my seven day trip from April 26th to May 3rd 2017. I applied four months in advance (on 23rd of December 2016) and received the result after four working days. It was a refusal due to: (picture attached)

My concern is that I did submit evidence about my educational status (Student verification from university, Absent leave letter from university - both are verified and translated into English) - but in the pack of documents they sent me back with my passport, I COULD NOT FIND THEM. I suspect there might be some mistake or maybe they took them out on purpose, but am for sure they were in my application when I submitted it at the visa centre.

FYI, my status is:

- I am a student (sophomore - in my second year at university).
- have not much income.
- my sponsor is my uncle who is so close to me because we were living together for nearly 15 years. My uncle owns a company on his own and gave me 9000$ for the trip. (However, there is no evidence of his income nor letter from him in my application).
- I provided my mom's incomes as well (1100$/month).

Can anyone give me advice: Should I apply or what kind of document should I provide them to make myself become more convincing?

Because I can't file an appeal there is almost no way for me to find out what happened with the papers from my university :( 
[image][image]

---

I am going to send a complaint to VFS centre took over my application via their website because it seems to be the only way to do it. Any advice on the complaint? 
[image]

Comment: Generally the advice we give to questions about UK visa refusals is to _quote or scan the exact, actual refusal text_ and include it in the question (with personal details redacted) rather than your own paraphrase of the text. UK refusal notices are pretty detailed, and the people who answer here are often able to notice minor details in the phrasing that the asker wouldn't have considered relevant.

Comment: Which VFS/VAC did you use? Normally we don't care which VFS but since you have a document discrepancy it's important to know.

Comment: @GayotFow There is only one VFS global centre in Hanoi, Vietnam and I used that. Do you think I should file a complaint against them to find out what happened with my papers?

Comment: @pnuts that means they didn't verify my sponsorship, doesn't it? So if I reapply, I need to give more information about my sponsor and his willing to bear the cost?

Comment: @TienLeThuy I will put some information into an answer, but take care that it may or may not apply to your situation.

Comment: @pnuts I dont have any copy of the list and can only say from my memory that it was written in the list. And yes I provided a list on my own as a requirement from VFS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a refusal because the ECO did not appear to examine evidence that was favourable to you. When your bundle was returned, the relevant documents were missing.

Last February there was an advisory stating that VFS personnel in south Asia, (viz Pakistan and India) were removing evidence. I don't know if this is happening in Vietnam or not, but it's worth taking note of it. This was also discussed in chat several times.  And I put a snippet into META about it.  It reconstructs a question I raised when I took a course in Schengen earlier in 2016...

[image]

Source: https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3709/1737

What this amalgamates to is that immediate representations are called for. The caveat is that while this has been observed for both India and Pakistan, there are no such observations for Vietnam at the moment.

If you think this has happened to you, then you should make urgent and emphatic representations; instructing a solicitor to handle it is the 'golden' solution, but nothing prevents an individual from engaging both the VFS and UKVI directly.

---

Also, they have a habit of not returning evidence that is photocopied or printed out from the net.  So if your stuff was not originals this could also be the case.  Also they will not return evidence that is forged or deceptive but hopefully this does not apply to you.

Comment: The student verification letters are missing, but it sounds like other relevant documents (uncle's sponsorship and bank statements) were never submitted at all, which might have some bearing on this case, no?

Comment: Thank you Gayot. Those missing documents are all originals and verified by my university.

Comment: @ZachLipton the bank statements are submitted I suppose because it is in the pack returned from the embassy (means they did take a look at it). But I didn't provide any letter from my uncle announcing he would pay for the trip (I didn't think it would be necessary). I should have

Comment: And also, I remembered there was a trainee involved in my case. When I submit all documents at VFS, a girl seemed to be a new trainee was instructed by the official who I gave my documents to.