# Why didn't the UK visa officer ask for financial documents?

Tags: uk, paperwork, tourist-visas

Recently, my parents had an interview in Pune for a UK tourist visa. They had originals of all of their bank statements and their passport with them, but the official did not ask them to submit them. Even though they asked, the officer said they were not needed. We were told that the official will ask for the originals of the passport and the financial documents, so we had not attached any photocopies to the application form, as well. Will this be a problem, and what should be done now?

Comment: That is unusual. Financial documents are typically required.

Comment: Is the issue, and confusion, that financial documents were not included with the application itself, thinking that taking the originals to the interview was all that was needed?

Comment: [Standard Visitor visa](https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/documents-you-must-provide)

`Documents you must provide

When you apply you’ll need to provide:

a current passport or other valid travel identification

evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, such as bank statements or payslips from the last 6 months`. From the rules it appears financial documents are **mandatory**. You will have to take it up with them.

Comment: are they known, wealthy individuals?
Could be that he has just taken it as fact that they obviously have enough money.

Answer (score 6):

If you read Gayot Fow's response to *[UK Standard Visitor visa refusal. Should I reapply?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85227/uk-standard-visitor-visa-refusal-should-i-reapply/85274#85274)* you notice that sometimes VFS officers are taking on authority they do not have and removing documents and declaring some unnecessary contrary to their training and instructions.

> Last February there was an advisory stating that VFS personnel in
>   south Asia, (viz Pakistan and India) were removing evidence.

Per [Visitor: supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf)

> **Section 1: documents you must provide – all visitors**
>
> Valid travel document (national passport or other document that allows
>   the holder to travel internationally)
>
> Section 2: other documents you **may want to provide** – all visitors
>
> This section provides guidance on the types of documents that you
>   **may want to provide** to help us consider your application against the Immigration Rules. Previous travel documents/passports, which show
>   previous travel. Financial documents showing that you have sufficient
>   funds available. These must clearly show that you have access to the
>   funds, such as: bank statements

I know of quite a few people [during the period when UK visas were by interview] who went for interviews and were granted without the ECO asking for anything in the form of supporting documents. From the rules it appears financial documents are **not absolutely mandatory**, nevertheless they are very typical. For now I will suggest take it up with them **if** your parents visa application is refused.

Answer (score 4):

my Parents got UK visa successfully. VFS office process is somewhat changed. Office is moved to paperless mode from paperwork. So they do not keep your financial documents, instead they get it scanned. Only Passport is kept at VFS for stamping purposes. Confusion is clear at least from my side. :-)