# Australian visit Visa refusal based on visa officer mistakes

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, australia

I need suggestions about that my brother visa is refused for Australia.

All the reasons that are written in the rejection letter do not belong to him. For example, he is not doing business, its written business, his previous travel history is also not the same, his don and bank names for his bank statement does also not belong to him.

Can any one help me, how can I tell them that the circumstances written do not belong to him?[image]

Comment: Please post the refusal letter with personal details blanked out in order for anyone to be able to give you a meaningful reply.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/132466/subclass-600-visa-refused-visa-officer-overlook-some-of-the-facts-what-are-my?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Traveller: If the OP's contention is that the refusal letter is so unrelated to his own situation that it must be _someone else's refusal_ sent to him by mistake, then I don't think seeing the actual letter will help us. An answer would be about what the right channels to get the clerical mistake fixed (and at least get _his own_ refusal) are. [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/111995/my-girlfriend-was-refused-a-tourist-visa) is similar -- but not a duplicate since it is about the UK rather than Australia.

Comment: @Henning Makholm I agree; I can’t find any reference to being able to challenge a decision but wondered if the refusal would shed any light on that. Otherwise the assumption would be that the only possibility would be to contact the local Embassy to ask for a review on the basis of the supposed error

Comment: it's quite common to not agree with the reasons your visa is refused. If you thought those reasons didn't apply you'd not have even attempted the application...

Comment: The total decision is looks like a clerical mistake, the written things dint belong to him at all or belong to submitted documents.

Comment: @jwenting Disagreement on subjective matters is common but the disagreement here is about matters of objective fact: it seems clear that the refusal letter relates to some other person's application.

Comment: 1-He never works for any computer organisation he is doing job in shoes sector n since last 5 year in the same company.2-he dint have any shares any where n in1996 he was 15 years old.3-he only provide one bank statement from SCB4- except china n england n dubai n Thailand he never travel to other countries. Now how can he ask for reviews n to whom???

Comment: I would probably start by using the VFS Global [contact us](https://www.vfsglobal.com/Australia/Pakistan/contact_us.html) facility to raise a complaint with the service provider.  If the error was not theirs, they should nonetheless escalate it to the high commission or consulate.  If this approach proves ineffective, you'll have to figure out how to make a complaint *about* VFS Global directly to the Australian high commission or consulate (or, failing that, to the [Department of Home Affairs back in Australia](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/)).

Comment: We have emailed islamabad High commission n they have acknowledged out email by send another refusal and that is the same almost. Thanks anyway